# Align two SwiftUI text views in HStack with correct alignment

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a simple list view that contains two rows.

Each row contains two text views. View one and View two.

I would like to align the last label (View two) in each row so that the name labels are leading aligned and keep being aligned regardless of font size.

The first label (View one) also needs to be leading aligned.

I've tried setting a min frame width on the first label (View One) but it doesn't work. It also seems impossible to set the min width and also to get a text view to be leading aligned in View One.

Any ideas? This is fairly straight forward in UIKit.

[image: List View]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've found a way to fix this that supports dynamic type and isn't hacky. The answer is using [PreferenceKeys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey) and [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader)!

The essence of this solution is that each number `Text` will have a width that it will be drawn with depending on its text size. `GeometryReader` can detect this width and then we can use `PreferenceKey` to bubble it up to the List itself, where the max width can be kept track of and then assigned to each number `Text`'s frame width.

A `PreferenceKey` is a type you create with an associated type (can be any struct conforming to `Equatable`, this is where you store the data about the preference) that is attached to any `View` and when it is attached, it bubbles up through the view tree and can be listened to in an ancestor view by using `.onPreferenceChange(PreferenceKeyType.self)`.

To start, we'll create our PreferenceKey type and the data it contains:

```
struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [WidthPreference]
    
    static var defaultValue: [WidthPreference] = []
    
    static func reduce(value: inout [WidthPreference], nextValue: () -> [WidthPreference]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

struct WidthPreference: Equatable {
    let width: CGFloat
}
```

Next, we'll create a View called `WidthPreferenceSettingView` that will be attached to the background of whatever we want to size (in this case, the number labels). This will take care of setting the preference which will pass up this number label's preferred width with PreferenceKeys.

```
struct WidthPreferenceSettingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.clear)
                .preference(
                    key: WidthPreferenceKey.self,
                    value: [WidthPreference(width: geometry.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.global).width)]
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, the list itself! We have an @State variable which is the width of the numbers "column" (not really a column in the sense that the numbers don't directly affect other numbers in code). Through `.onPreferenceChange(WidthPreference.self)` we listen to changes in the preference we created and store the max width in our width state. After all of the number labels have been drawn and their width read by the GeometryReader, the widths propagate back up and the max width is assigned by `.frame(width: width)`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var width: CGFloat? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("1. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(WidthPreferenceSettingView())
                Text("John Smith")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("20. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(WidthPreferenceSettingView())
                Text("Jane Done")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("2000. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(WidthPreferenceSettingView())
                Text("Jax Dax")
            }
        }.onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
            for p in preferences {
                let oldWidth = self.width ?? CGFloat.zero
                if p.width > oldWidth {
                    self.width = p.width
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have multiple columns of data, one way to scale this is to make an enum of your columns or to index them, and the @State for width would become a dictionary where each key is a column and `.onPreferenceChange` compares against the key-value for the max width of a column.

To show results, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Z6d.png) is what it looks like with larger text turned on, works like a charm :).

This article on PreferenceKey and inspecting the view tree helped tremendously: https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/

Comment: The `action` closure of `onPreferenceChange` can be reduced to `self.width = preferences.map(\.width).max()`.  Your version is extremely verbose; all the code needs to do is set `self.width` to the largest width in the preferences.

Comment: Why did you use the name `CenteringView`? This view isn't centering anything. It's measuring the width of the view that it's layered behind.

Comment: @PeterSchorn that's a good call-out, thank you! I updated the names to try and better reflect the purpose of each type.

Answer (score 14):

From iOS16 you can do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var rowData: [RowData] = RowData.sample
    var body: some View {
        Grid(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Some sort of title")
            ForEach(RowData.sample) { row in
                GridRow {
                    Text(row.id)
                    Text(row.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct RowData: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    static var sample: [Self] = [.init(id: "1", name: "Joe"), .init(id: "1000", name: "Diana")]
}
```

---

**Previous answer**

Here are three options to do it statically.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var width: CGFloat? = 100

    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("1. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                // Option 1
                Text("John Smith")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    //.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("20. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                // Option 2 (works mostly like option 1)
                Text("Jane Done")
                    .background(Color.green)
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                Text("2000. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                // Option 3 - takes all the rest space to the right
                Text("Jax Dax")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks:
[image: simulator1]

We may calculate the width based on the longenst entry as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56590449).

There is couple of options to dynamically calculate width.

**Option 1**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct WidthGetter: View {
    let widthChanged: PassthroughSubject<CGFloat, Never>
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { (g) -> Path in
            print("width: \(g.size.width), height: \(g.size.height)")
            self.widthChanged.send(g.frame(in: .global).width)
            return Path() // could be some other dummy view
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let event = PassthroughSubject<CGFloat, Never>()

    @State private var width: CGFloat?

    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("1. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .background(WidthGetter(widthChanged: event))
 
                // Option 1
                Text("John Smith")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    //.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("20. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .background(WidthGetter(widthChanged: event))
                // Option 2 (works mostly like option 1)
                Text("Jane Done")
                    .background(Color.green)
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                Text("2000. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .background(WidthGetter(widthChanged: event))
                // Option 3 - takes all the rest space to the right
                Text("Jax Dax")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }.onReceive(event) { (w) in
            print("event ", w)
            if w > (self.width ?? .zero) {
                self.width = w
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var width: CGFloat?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("1. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { dimension in
                        self.width = max(self.width ?? 0, dimension.width)
                        return dimension[.leading]
                    })
                
                // Option 1
                Text("John Smith")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    //.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("20. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { dimension in
                        self.width = max(self.width ?? 0, dimension.width)
                        return dimension[.leading]
                    })
                // Option 2 (works mostly like option 1)
                Text("Jane Done")
                    .background(Color.green)
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                Text("2000. ")
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { dimension in
                        self.width = max(self.width ?? 0, dimension.width)
                        return dimension[.leading]
                    })
                // Option 3 - takes all the rest space to the right
                Text("Jax Dax")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: simulator2]

Comment: This answer is really helpful ... I align more then 3 item with `.frame(minWidth: 100,idealWidth: 150,maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .leading)` ... this approch is working realy fine ...

Answer (score 13):

With Swift 5.2 and iOS 13, you can use [`PreferenceKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey) protocol, [`preference(key:value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3278633-preference) method and [`onPreferenceChange(_:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader/3268620-onpreferencechange) method to solve this problem.

You can implement the code for the `View` proposed by OP in 3 major steps, as shown below.

---

### #1. Initial implementation

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Text("5.")
                    Text("John Smith")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("20.")
                    Text("Jane Doe")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Challenge")
        }
    }

}
```

---

### #2. Intermediate implementation (set equal width)

The idea here is to collect all the widths for the `Text`s that represent a rank and assign the widest among them to the `width` property of `ContentView`.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {

    static var defaultValue: [CGFloat] = []
    static func reduce(value: inout [CGFloat], nextValue: () -> [CGFloat]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var width: CGFloat? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Text("5.")
                        .overlay(
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                Color.clear
                                    .preference(
                                        key: WidthPreferenceKey.self,
                                        value: [proxy.size.width]
                                    )
                            }
                        )
                        .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("John Smith")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("20.")
                        .overlay(
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                Color.clear
                                    .preference(
                                        key: WidthPreferenceKey.self,
                                        value: [proxy.size.width]
                                    )
                            }
                        )
                        .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("Jane Doe")
                }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) { widths in
                if let width = widths.max() {
                    self.width = width
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Challenge")
        }
    }

}
```

---

### #3. Final implementation (with some refactoring)

To make our code reusable, we can refactor our `preference` logic into a `ViewModifier`.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {

    static var defaultValue: [CGFloat] = []
    static func reduce(value: inout [CGFloat], nextValue: () -> [CGFloat]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }

}

struct EqualWidth: ViewModifier {

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(
                            key: WidthPreferenceKey.self,
                            value: [proxy.size.width]
                        )
                }
            )
    }

}

extension View {
    func equalWidth() -> some View {
        modifier(EqualWidth())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var width: CGFloat? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Text("5.")
                        .equalWidth()
                        .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("John Smith")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("20.")
                        .equalWidth()
                        .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("Jane Doe")
                }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) { widths in
                if let width = widths.max() {
                    self.width = width
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Challenge")
        }
    }

}
```

---

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I just had to deal with this. The solutions that rely on a fixed width `frame` won't work for dynamic type, so I couldn't use them. The way I got around it was by putting the flexible item (the left number in this case) in a `ZStack` with a placeholder containing the widest allowable content, and then setting the placeholder's opacity to 0:

```swift
ZStack {
    Text("9999")
        .opacity(0)
        .accessibility(visibility: .hidden)
    Text(id)
}
```

It's pretty hacky, but at least it supports dynamic type ‍♂️

[image: ZStack with placeholder]

Full example below!

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Person: Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
}

struct IDBadge : View {
    var id: Int
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text("9999.") // The maximum width dummy value
                .font(.headline)
                .opacity(0)
                .accessibility(visibility: .hidden)
            Text(String(id) + ".")
                .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var people: [Person]
    var body: some View {
        List(people) { person in
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                IDBadge(id: person.id)
                Text(person.name)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static let people = [Person(name: "John Doe", id: 1), Person(name: "Alexander Jones", id: 2000), Person(name: "Tom Lee", id: 45)]
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView(people: people)
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 320.0, height: 150.0))
            ContentView(people: people)
                .environment(\.sizeCategory, .accessibilityMedium)
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 320.0, height: 200.0))
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: This seems interesting @mbxDev - will have to take a look at this. Nice one.

Comment: Let me know if this works out for you @Edward! I've been using this more in my current app.

Comment: Hi - thank you for this! But for some strange reason, I get an error on `.trailing` when I have the two `Text` elements like in your example; but if I only have one `Text` element, I do not. The error is "static member 'trailing' cannot be used on instance of type 'Alignment'". It's strange that the number of `Text` elements causes this? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I figured this out. Swift's compiler is so maddening. The line should be `.accessibility(hidden: true)`.

Comment: Normally I don't like such hacks, but it's simplicity makes it actually quite elegant 

Answer (score 5):

You can just have your two `Text`s and then a `Spacer` in an `HStack`. The `Spacer` will push your `Text`s to the left, and everything will self-adjust if either `Text`s change size due to the length of their content:

```
HStack {
    Text("1.")
    Text("John Doe")
    Spacer()
}
.padding()
```

[image]

The `Text`s are technically center-aligned, but since the views automatically resize and only take up as much space as the text inside of it (since we did not explicitly set a frame size), and are pushed to the left by the `Spacer`, they appear left-aligned. The benefit of this over setting a fixed width is that you don't have to worry about text being truncated.

Also, I added padding to the `HStack` to make it look nicer, but if you want to adjust how close the `Text`s are to each other, you can manually set the padding on any of its sides. (You can even set negative padding to push items closer to each other than their natural spacing).

**Edit**

Didn't realize OP needed the second `Text` to be vertically aligned as well. I have a way to do it, but its "hacky" and wouldn't work for larger font sizes without more work:

These are the data objects:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
    init(name: String, id: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

class People {
    var people: [Person]
    init(people: [Person]) {
        self.people = people
    }
    func maxIDDigits() -> Int {
        let maxPerson = people.max { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
            p1.id < p2.id
        }
        print(maxPerson!.id)
        let digits = log10(Float(maxPerson!.id)) + 1
        return Int(digits)
    }
    func minTextWidth(fontSize: Int) -> Length {
        print(maxIDDigits())
        print(maxIDDigits() * 30)
        return Length(maxIDDigits() * fontSize)
    }
}
```

This is the `View`:

```
var people = People(people: [Person(name: "John Doe", id: 1), Person(name: "Alexander Jones", id: 2000), Person(name: "Tom Lee", id: 45)])
var body: some View {   
    List {
        ForEach(people.people.identified(by: \.id)) { person in                
            HStack {
                Text("\(person.id).")
                    .frame(minWidth: self.people.minTextWidth(fontSize: 12), alignment: .leading)
                Text("\(person.name)")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make it work for multiple font sizes, you would have to get the font size and pass it into the `minTextWidth(fontSize:)`.

Again, I'd like to emphasize that this is "hacky" and probably goes against SwiftUI principles, but I could not find a built in way to do the layout you asked for (probably because the `Text`s in different rows do not interact with each other, so they have no way of knowing how to stay vertically aligned with each other).

**Edit 2**
The above code generates this:

[image: Code result]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Edward then I’m confused on what your question is. Do you not want the texts to be leading in the view? This has the same result as that. Test it out for yourself.

Comment: see the image in my question. it relates to multiple rows. Basically you have two labels in a HStack - how can you ensure that the second labels are aligned in a list whilst keeping both labels in a row (cell) leading aligned?

Comment: @Edward Edited my answer now that I understand your question better.

Comment: awesome! thanks for your answer, I think the "hacky" way is the only way at the moment.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help, and let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a fixed width to a number `Text` view. It makes this `Text` component with a fixed size.

[image]

```
HStack {
        Text(item.number)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .frame(width: 30)
        Text(item.name)
}
```

The drawback of this solution is that, if you will have a longer text there, it will be wrapped and ended with "...", but in that case I think you can roughly estimate which width will be enough.

Comment: hey @kamwysoc the problem with this approach is that the first label text isn't actually leading. It seems to get overridden by the frame modifier. Also I don't think this would work for larger text sizes.

Answer (score 2):

If 1 line limit is ok with you:

```
Group {
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text("Vehicle:")
            Text("Lot:")
            Text("Zone:")
            Text("Location:")
            Text("Price:")
        }
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("vehicle")
            Text("lot")
            Text("zone")
            Text("location")
            Text("price")
        }
    }
    .lineLimit(1)
    .font(.footnote)
    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
HStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("5.")
            }
            .frame(width: 40)

            Text("Jon Smith")
        }
```

But this will only work with fix width.
`.frame(minWidth: 40)` will fill the entire View because of `Space()`

`.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)` don't have any effect in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to get this to work for a full day I came up with this solution:

[image: example picture]

EDIT: [Link to Swift Package](https://github.com/potmo/SameSizeContainer)

```
import SwiftUI

fileprivate extension Color {
    func exec(block: @escaping ()->Void) -> Self {
        block()
        return self
    }
}

fileprivate class Deiniter {
    let block: ()->Void
    init(block: @escaping ()->Void) {
        self.block = block
    }
    deinit {
       block()
    }
}
struct SameWidthContainer<Content: View>: View {
    private var id: UUID
    private let deiniter: Deiniter
    @ObservedObject private var group: WidthGroup
    private var content: () -> Content
    
    init(group: WidthGroup, content: @escaping ()-> Content) {
        self.group = group
        self.content = content
        
        let id = UUID()
        self.id = id
        

        WidthGroup.widths[group.id]?[id] = 100.0
        self.deiniter = Deiniter() {
            WidthGroup.widths[group.id]?.removeValue(forKey: id)
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: self.group.width, height: 1)
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
            
            content()
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .exec {
                                WidthGroup.widths[self.group.id]?[self.id] = proxy.size.width
                                let newWidth = WidthGroup.widths[group.id]?.values.max() ?? 0
                                if newWidth != self.group.width {
                                    self.group.width = newWidth
                                }
                            }
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}

class WidthGroup: ObservableObject {

    static var widths: [UUID: [UUID: CGFloat]] = [:]
    @Published var width: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    let id: UUID
    
    init() {
        let id = UUID()
        self.id = id
        
        WidthGroup.widths[id] = [:]
    }
    
    deinit {
        WidthGroup.widths.removeValue(forKey: id)
    }
}

struct SameWidthText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    private static let GROUP = WidthGroup()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            SameWidthContainer(group: Self.GROUP) {
                Text("One")
            }
                
            SameWidthContainer(group: Self.GROUP) {
                Text("Two")
            }
            SameWidthContainer(group: Self.GROUP)  {
                Text("Three")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is then used like this:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    
    @State private var group1 = WidthGroup()
    @State private var group2 = WidthGroup()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            ForEach(9..<12) { index in
                HStack {
                    SameWidthContainer(group: group1) {
                        Text("All these will have same width in group 1 \(index)")
                    }
                    
                    Text("Some other text")
                    
                    SameWidthContainer(group: group2) {
                        Text("All these will have same width in group 2 \(index)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If one of the views grows or shrinks all the views in the same group will grow/shrink with it. I just got it to work so I haven't tried it that much.
It's a bit of a hack but, hey, it doesn't seem to be another way than hacking.

Comment: I made a swift package with examples for those interested [here](https://github.com/potmo/SameSizeContainer)

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 12.5**

If you know the amount you want to offset the second view by, then you can place both views in a leading aligned `ZStack` and use the `.padding(.horizontal, amount)` modifier on the second view to offset it.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(persons) { person in
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(person.number)
                    Text(person.name)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Challenge")
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I think the correct way to do this would be using `HorizontalAlignment`. Something like:

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum LeadingName : AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> Length { d[.leading] }
    }
    static let leadingName = HorizontalAlignment(LeadingName.self)
}

List (people.identified(by: \.id)) {person in
    HStack {
        Text("\(person.id)")
        Text("\(person.name)").alignmentGuide(.leadingName) {d in d[.leading]}
    }
}
```

But I can't get it to work.

I can't find any examples of this with a List. It seems that List doesn't support alignment (yet?)

I can sort of get it to work with a VStack, and hard coded values like:

```
        VStack (alignment: .leadingName ) {
        HStack {
            Text("1.")
            Text("John Doe").alignmentGuide(.leadingName) {d in d[.leading]}
            Spacer()
        }
        HStack {
            Text("2000.")
            Text("Alexander Jones").alignmentGuide(.leadingName) {d in d[.leading]}
            Spacer()
        }
        HStack {
            Text("45.")
            Text("Tom Lee").alignmentGuide(.leadingName) {d in d[.leading]}
            Spacer()
        }
    }
```

I'm hoping this will be fixed in a later beta...

Comment: Brilliant explanation of alignment in all it's forms at: https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/