# Multiple controls on same line in SwiftUI macOS form

Tags: swift, macos, forms, user-interface, swiftui

I am making a UI to change the 3D coordinates of an object, and I thought it would make sense to put all three on the same line with a label beforehand, sort of like **System Preferences** does for number separators :
[image: Number Separators in Systemm Preferences]

However, doing so messes up the alignment of the whole form, and I'm not sure how to resolve this (*except by adding `VStack`s and `HStack`s everywhere, which I really hope is not the best available solution*) :
[image: My messed up UI]

Here is the code driving the view :

```swift
struct ObjectSettingsView: View {
    @State var object : Object
    
    var body : some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Name:", text: $object.name, prompt : Text("New Object"))
            Toggle(
                "Visible",
                isOn: $object.visible
            )
            Divider()
            HStack {
                Text("Coordinates:")
                NumberView(label : "X:", number : object.coordinates.x)
                NumberView(label : "Y:", number : object.coordinates.y)
                NumberView(label : "Z:", number : object.coordinates.z)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NumberView : View{
    var label : String
    @State var number : Int32
    
    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(
                self.label,
                value: self.$number,
                formatter: NumberFormatter()
            )
            Stepper("", value: self.$number, in: 1...8)
                .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

( *I know this really should be using a `ViewModel`, I'm just trying to figure out how forms work right now* )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add @Binding and LazyVGrid to your Code.

Maybe this helps:

```
struct ObjectData {
    var name: String = "New Object"
    var visible: Bool = true
    var coordinates_x: Int32 = 0
    var coordinates_y: Int32 = 0
    var coordinates_z: Int32 = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = ObjectData()

    let columns = [
        GridItem(alignment: .trailing),
        GridItem(alignment: .leading),
    ]

    var form: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            Text("Name:")
            TextField("", text: $data.name)
            Text("blind").opacity(0)
            Toggle("Visible:", isOn: $data.visible)
            Text("Coordinates:")
            HStack {
                NumberView(label : "X:", number : $data.coordinates_x)
                NumberView(label : "Y:", number : $data.coordinates_y)
                NumberView(label : "Z:", number : $data.coordinates_z)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack() {
            form
            Text(" --- Check --- ")
            Text(String(describing: data))
        }
        .frame(width: 400.0)
    }
    
}

struct NumberView : View{
    var label : String
    @Binding var number : Int32
    
    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(
                self.label,
                value: self.$number,
                formatter: NumberFormatter()
            )
            Stepper("", value: self.$number, in: 1...8)
                .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That partially solves the problem by aligning everything to the right. Not what I wanted, but at least it's aligned xD

Comment: Removed the Form-View  and fixed the width in outer View brings better results. See edited code.

Comment: Now that's almost perfect ! The last problem is that the label column should fit no more than the longest label in there, whereas here it takes up half of the space regardless. I'm looking up how to do that right now but if you know how please do tell 

Comment: Preferably that would mean the left column adapts to the width of the labels, not having to choose the width manually

Comment: I have tried adapting this answer, but I can't get it to work for this context : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588332/align-two-swiftui-text-views-in-hstack-with-correct-alignment

Comment: About the left column see my new code below.

Answer (score 0):

Separating things into two `Form`s almost does the trick, although labels are still not exactly aligned as in system Preferences :

[image]

```swift
struct ObjectSettingsView: View {
    @State var object : Object
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Name:", text: $object.name, prompt : Text("New Object"))
                Toggle("Visible", isOn: $object.visible)
            }
            Divider()
            Form {
                HStack {
                    Text("Coordinates:")
                    NumberView(label : "X:", number : object.coordinates.x)
                    NumberView(label : "Y:", number : object.coordinates.y)
                    NumberView(label : "Z:", number : object.coordinates.z)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// static let left = GridItem.Size.flexible(minimum: 10, maximum: .infinity)
static let left = GridItem.Size.flexible(minimum: 40, maximum: 100)
static let right = GridItem.Size.flexible(minimum: 40, maximum: 200)
let columns = [
    GridItem(left, alignment: .trailing),
    GridItem(right, alignment: .leading),
]
```

The problem is that the size structs are set to .infinity
I changed the column settings like above with fixed max values.
To get all infos see Apple Docs about GridItem.